# Error when booting live-usb device

Tags: live-usb, root-filesystem

While booting a live-usb system, the following errors are returned:

```
Attempting to mount media /dev/sda2
[...] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[...] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[...] EXT4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
[...] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Skipping /dev/sda2 (marker '/mnt/cdrom///rescure/livecd/squashfs' does not exist)


/dev/loop0 is an invalid root device..
Could not find the root block device in .
```

What may be the problem and how to solve it?
Or where to better look for a solution?

Edit: replaced my typo in the post "uit" with "uid" as in the original error message.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a typo in the configuration. I am unaware of any option called "uit". However, the very common option of "uid" is likely, and in many modern distros the first User ID would be 1000, thus "uid=1000" is a likely candidate.

Did you create this live image? If it is something you downloaded from a project, maybe it is a bug they have since fixed, or could benefit from having a bug-report registered.

Comment: Sorry, "uit" was my typo in the post here. I now replaced the typo  "uit" above with "uid", as in the original error message.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not the question belongs here as a Unix&Linux forum.

Comment: Hence, my note above "where to better look for a solution?"

I tried several live systems, some of which didn't boot at all. The above errors are from a Bitdefender live .iso, that, according to this forum post recently has been discontinued: 
https://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?/topic/80237-new-rescue-cd-does-not-work-on-win10-64bitversion-1803/&tab=comments#comment-288847

I will check the UEFI/BIOS settings, as suggested in this thread as soon as I have the opportunity.

In any case, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Erm...what operating system is this live usb?

Comment: Here: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-bitdefender-rescue-cd-on-a-usb-flash-drive/#more-4405   
they say: "Bitdefender Rescue CD is a free bootable anti virus scanner created by Bitdefender and based on the Knoppix Linux Operating System."

Answer (score 0):

try disabling secure boot from BIOS. In my case I have a very old BIOS and found Data Execution Prevention (DEP) on the BIOS  (boot menu). Cheers.